# Populate NSMutableArray from another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'd like to extract the friends' name of each of my five selected friends from a `FBFriendPicker`, and put them on a `NSMutableArray`.

```
for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection) {
    [self.SelectedFriendsname addObject:user.name]; 
    NSLog(@"Friend selected: %@", user.name);
}
NSLog(@"my friends are %@", self.SelectedFriendsname);
```

The "friend selected" line appears on console and works fine, but my array stays empty `((null) on console)`
How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you alloc init your array like `self.SelectedFriendsname = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Comment: Damn now I feel dumb, thank you very much ! Resolved

Comment: Could one of you post the solution as an answer, and the author validate it? It will be clearer for other users.

Comment: I'll do it, and validate it
EDIT: since i'm a new user I can't answer my own question for 8 more hours, so I just edited my question.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution from @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani.*

`SelectedFriendsname` is not initialized.

### Objective-C

Resolved by preceding the loop with:

```
self.SelectedFriendsname = [NSMutableArray array];
```

### Swift

You can directly map values instead of looping:

```
SelectedFriendsname = friendPickerController.selection.map { $0.name }
```